# Percentage width and height hides background image

Tags: html, css

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/nhg33xek/)

```
  .moving_background
  {
    background-image: url("../image/quote3.jpg");
    background-position: 50% center; /*Centering property*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border:1px solid;
   }
```

If i change the width and height to 100%, it is not showing the border to me. I don't understand the reason. **Please let me know this**

I am trying to center this div in the body. Any other ways are also welcome except negative top, left, margin values.

Any idea?

Comment: You can use `width; auto`, to center horizontally your background. http://codepen.io/Magador/pen/ZYdVpz

Comment: Remove height or set it in percentage, you can see only one line. Just try with some avail images in the online. It ll not show you the image

Comment: It's because the height of the element is defined by the height of its content. But there is no content

Comment: As defined in the [W3C Specification: Visual formatting model details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#x12): "The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block"

Comment: Yes I understand it. I am setting height is 100%. So it should take the height of body. Isn't? Please correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: It should take the height of the content of the element. So if you set `<div class="moving_background"></div>`, the height of the `div` will be the height of its content, nothing.

Comment: One thing you can do is to place an `<img src="your.background.com/image.ext">` inside the background `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `background-image` does not count as content in your `div`, so what you have is an empty `div`, hence it has no height. A way around this is to add the image inside the `div`, then hide it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="moving_background">
    <image src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="background"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.moving_background {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
    background-position: 50% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid;
}

.background {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhg33xek/4/

Comment: Nononono. Just consider body is the container. If you set 100% width to container[body in my case `body{width:100%}`] and **Replace 100px height in the moving_background with 100% and similaryly width** It will not show you the image. I understand no content is in my div. But my image is there. how do i show it up?

Comment: Yes Thanks. Can i move `<img>` tag in moving backgrounds. Move in the sense `Moving multiple background images with keyframes`

Comment: That depends on what you are using to animate it, but I would suspect you would be able to as long as you select the correct element.